# Replace all occurrence of {{var}} to value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains an identifier

```
"Hello {{name}}, you are {{age}} years old."
```

Example object:

```
let valueMap = {name: 'jeff', age: 26}
```

What is the best way of converting this into:

```
"Hello jeff, you are 26 years old."
```

My current code is:

```
let string = 'Hello {{name}}, {{name}} you are {{age}} years old. {{wtf}}';

let objMap = {
  name: 'deojeff',
  age: 26,
}

let parsedString

let matched = string.match(/[^\{{.+}]+(?=}})/g)

let replaced = string.replace(/[^\{{.+}]+(?=}})/g, (args) => {
  return objMap[args] !== undefined ? objMap[args] : args
})

console.log(replaced) 
// Hello {{deojeff}}, {{deojeff}} you are {{26}} years old. {{wtf}}
```

But it includes the `{{` `}}`, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What should the code do with `{{wtf}}` ? Remove it ? Keep it ?

Comment: It should keep it. As it doesn't have any match in the `objMap`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [replace angular expressions with static values in a string](//stackoverflow.com/q/37432939), [How can I replace with more values in a text?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36642331) and [Javascript insert variables at a specific place in a string](//stackoverflow.com/q/36529417)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var string = 'Hello {{name}}, {{name}} you are {{age}} years old. {{wtf}}';
var objMap = {
  name: 'deojeff',
  age: 26,
};
for (var prop in objMap) {
  if (objMap.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    string = string.replace(new RegExp('{{' + prop + '}}', "g"), objMap[prop]);
  }
}
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Woah! This is works and it's clean as well. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is many template parser libraries available. you can use one of them.
dot is one of them which you can refer [here](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) .

Answer (score 0):

Just change you replace function to:

```
let replaced = string.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, (args, arg0) => {
  return objMap[arg0] !== undefined ? objMap[arg0] : args
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = 'Hello {{name}}, {{name}} you are {{age}} years old. {{wtf}}';

var objMap = {
  name: 'deojeff',
  age: 26,
}

var matched = string.match(/[^\{{.+}]+(?=}})/g)

var replaced = string.replace(/(\{{.*?\}})/g, function (m, $1){
      //choping of {{}} from start and end so that we dget key
      var key = $1.slice(2, -2);;
      return objMap[key] || ' ';
  });

console.log(replaced) 
// Hello {{deojeff}}, {{deojeff}} you are {{26}} years old. {{wtf}}
```

Comment: Sorry, you should keep `{{wtf}}` as it is. Use `return objMap[key] || m;` in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using es6 you could always backticks (template literals).

```
let obj = {
  name: 'deojeff',
  age: 26,
}

let string = `Hello ${name}, ${name} you are ${age} years old.`

console.log(string)
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: I am using ES6. But the string will be the input from the user so we are trying to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Oh, ok. Your right, this would only make sense if users didn't write the strings.

Answer (score 0):

This will be work. also, replace `{{wtf}}` to .

```js
const string = 'Hello {{name}}, {{name}} you are {{age}} years old. {{wtf}}';

const objMap = {
  name: 'deojeff',
  age: 26,
}

// const matched = string.match(/(?:\{{2})([^\}])+(?:\}{2})/g);

const replaced = string.replace(/(?:\{{2})([^\}])+(?:\}{2})/g, (args) => {
  const parsedArgs = args.replace(/\{|\}/g, '');
  return objMap[parsedArgs] !== undefined ? objMap[parsedArgs] : '';
});
```